# Python: Only accept specific IP (socket)

Tags: python, sockets, connection

I have a program that consists of a java client and a python server. The python server can recieve multiple connections and the clients will try to connect to the server every 17 seconds. 
My question:
The server should only accept one connection with the IP the user typed in before.

```
HOST = '0.0.0.0'
PORT = 1979

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print 'Socket created!'

try:
        s.bind((HOST, PORT))
except socket.error as e:
    print(e)
        sys.exit()

print 'Socket bind complete'

s.settimeout(30)
s.listen(10)

print 'Listening...'

timeout = 8

timeout_start = time.time()

while time.time() < timeout_start + timeout:
    try:
            conn, addr = s.accept()
        msg = conn.recv(1024)
        print ('--------------------------------------')
        print (msg) 
    except socket.timeout as e:
        print(e,': No client out there :(')
        s.close()
        break

        print 'Client connected: ' + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1])
    print ('--------------------------------------')

s.close()
```

This socket accepts all incoming connections. I want to add this before the socket:

```
connectip = raw_input('Please enter the IP of the client you want to connect to ')
```

and then the socket should only accept the client with the IP the user specified in "connectip".

Please pardon my bad english

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will still have to accept it, but you can close it before you transfer any data.

```
connectip = raw_input("Please enter the IP of the client you want to connect to ")
conn, addr = s.accept()
if addr[0] != connectip:
    conn.shutdown(SHUT_RDWR)
    conn.close()
else:
    # do what ever you want here
```

On a side note, you should really be switching to python 3, as python 2 is going to be deprecated very soon.

Comment: @MireiKadia no problem :)

Comment: Just to clarify... `shutdown` is unnecessary here. Everything done by `shutdown` is also done by `close`. (Indeed `shutdown` is rarely needed at all; it's for very specific situations where you want to signal that you won't be sending more data, or where you want to ignore further received data, *without* closing the socket.)